# Android Service (pause/resume)

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, service

Здравствуйте.Возник нетривиальный вопрос.

Есть *Android IntentService*, который запускается и останавливается по:

```
// start button
startService(testIntent);

// stop button
stopService(testIntent);
```

все прекрасно работает, сервис крутится, нотификации идут. Но стало надобно научить его приостанавливаться. То есть, сделать ему

```
onPause();
onResume();
```

подскажите как это воплотить. Спасибо.

Comment: при условии что делать паузы и возобновления на уровне сервиса. И не лезть в те методы которые он крутит.

Comment: Нужно определиться для начала, что такое пауза. Просто не отсылать нотификации или даже не обрабатывать их.

В большинстве случаев пауза - это просто сохранение текущего состояния и остановка. А resume - это старт с инициализацией сохраненным состоянием.

Answer (score 1):

А что имеется ввиду под "приостанавливаться"? Он должен перестать чего-то-там делать или вообще "умирать" на какое-то время?
Вообще все эти действия очень красочно представлены в Samples ApiDemos.
Просто поставьте тебе примеры из SDK, там сделайте поиск по названиям файлов Service, получите штук 8 примеров по всем типам сервисов. 
Думаю Вам нужен вариант с сообщениями. Тупа отослать ему: СПАТЬ! И он "приостанавливается", потом послать: ВСТАТЬ! И он скирдует дальше.

PS: да я имел ввиду ApiDemos пример...